# How to read score from stockfish - inconsistent response every call?

Tags: engines, stockfish, uci

I was setup stockfish with:

```
uci
setoption name hash value 128
setoption name threads value 4
```

That I try to evaluate my first moves to learn how it works (I am programmer) but I received random results.

```
go depth 20
```

First result cp = 16

```
info depth 20 seldepth 30 multipv 1 score cp 16 nodes 1327846 nps 1074309 hashfull 585 tbhits 0 time 1236 pv e2e4 e7e6 d2d4 d7d5 e4d5 e6d5 f1d3 g8f6 g1f3 f8d6 e1g1 e8g8 b1c3 c7c6 f3e5 f8e8 c1f4 f6g4 f1e1 d6e5 f4e5 g4e5 e1e5
bestmove e2e4 ponder e7e6
```

Second result cp = 20.

```
info depth 20 seldepth 29 multipv 1 score cp 20 nodes 4912037 nps 1040685 hashfull 986 tbhits 0 time 4720 pv e2e4 e7e6 d2d4 d7d5 e4d5 e6d5 f1d3 g8f6 g1f3 f8d6 e1g1 e8g8 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c6b4 c3b5 h7h6 b5d6 d8d6
bestmove e2e4 ponder e7e6
```

Why each time Stockfish produce something else for 20 depth - different **scores** - same move **e2e4**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple - `hashing`. The first time you run the analysis, the engine stored the computed positions in a hash-table. This table was not **clear** the next time you run the analysis. Next time, when you ran the same analysis, the engine could search further and thus returned a different score for it's principal variation.

Evidence? Note the node counts was: `1327846` for your first attempt and `4912037` for your second attempt. The NPS (nodes per second) was very close (`1074309` vs `1040685`). Clearly Stockfish used the existing hash-table to skip moves it had already computed in your first attempt.

Note that this is an expected behaviors, clearing hash-table after each move would dramatically reduce the engine strength.

Comment: I still not understand it clearly. When I specify 20 depth it should give same results but it looks that hashtable has some impact every iteration. I assume that 20 depth need always same nps and not understand it need more nps next time?

Comment: @Chameleon Chess engine isn't that simple. The engine would search over depth 20 like q-search if necessary.

Comment: @Chameleon: (old post I know) The engine does not do a complete traversal, but skips nodes; compare seldepth with depth; seldepth often is a maximum search depth, depth itself more like a typical depth for selected nodes